# Outlet Wiring Identification

Tags: electrical, receptacle

I'm replacing an outlet and I don't know which wires attach to which screws. I'm partially color-blind, and two of the wires look like different shades of red and one looks black. I know that the black wire should be attached to one of the brass screws, but I need help identifying the other 2 wires.

[image]

Additional Angles:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

This is the old outlet:

[image]

And the new outlet:

[image]

Comment: Color rending online isn't great either (at least as far as what I get). #1 looks white, leaving #2 would have to be ground, but if that's the same wire coming out of the back of the box I might judge differently.I would definitely like to see another camera angle into the box.

Comment: Can you pull the switch out of the box without disconnecting it at all and snap us another photo of the inside of the box please?

Comment: @NoSparksPlease I added additional pics.

Comment: In your pics you have the receptacles "upside down" for the normal residential (vertical) installation. Normally the ground is down, the shorter slot (hot) is on the right and the longer slot (neutral) is on the left. So normally black and red wires are attached on the right and white on the left. (For some reason hospitals install these with the ground up.)

Comment: @JimStewart That's interesting about hospitals. I found this informative explanation: https://www.archtoolbox.com/materials-systems/electrical/groundorientation.html

Comment: @JimStewart You may find it interesting that there was a time I remember back around 1990 that several of the parts houses posted a bulletin from one of the receptacle manufacturers warning that Hospital Grade receptacles were only submitted for testing to UL in the ground up position. It seems this is no longer current.

Answer (score 1):

### You'll want a few extra parts for this

The wiring runs in this box appear to have been made using new-style armored cable (AC) that has a bonding strip in it, which means that you don't have a ground wire; instead, the combination of the cable armor and bonding strip serves as the grounding path.  As a result, you'll either need to return your receptacle and get one with a *self-grounding* feature (in addition to tamper-resistance, that is!), or get a *ground pigtail* that you can screw into the designated grounding hole in the back of the box to provide a ground wire to the receptacle's grounding screw.  (You also may need to return the receptacle anyway, since it won't fit the existing faceplate as it's decorator-style (big rectangular opening) vs using a standard (two roundish openings) receptacle opening on a faceplate.)

While you're there, get a short length (3-6") of black 12AWG THHN and a wirenut suitable for three 12AWG wires.  Once you return with the right things, you'll then need to strip the insulation off the ends of the black wire you bought, and use the wirenut to combine it with the existing black and red wires in the box -- crank it down *tight* and make sure it passes a pull test!  Then, you can install the ground pigtail and wire it to the green screw on the new receptacle if you went that route.  Once that's done, the black pigtail goes to the brass screw and the existing (yellowish) white pigtail goes to the silver screw on the receptacle; once the receptacle's all wired up, you can button things back up, turn the power back on, and enjoy your work!

Comment: Tx! I intend to go to Home Depot tomorrow and get the self-grounding standard roundish outlet, as I didn't realize the rectangular type won't fit the faceplate. So I won't be using the ground pigtail. Is it necessary to combine the black and red wires? I'd prefer to install the new outlet exactly as it was when I took the old one out. If I can do it that way then where should I screw the red wire? And I take it you've identified #1 in the pic as the "yellowish white" wire?

Comment: Also just curious, but when did "new-style armored cable" come on the market? This outlet probably hasn't been changed in 30+ years, so wondering if the "new-style" doesn't suggest it's a recent technology.

Comment: @whitewings -- indeed, #1 is the "yellowish white" wire, also, while you *could* land the red wire on one brass screw and the black wire on the other brass screw, pigtailing as I describe is generally preferred because it means that the next person who wants to swap this outlet has will have an easier time of it.  Also, new-style AC came on the market sometime in the 1960s or so as I understand it? (Keep in mind that BX, the 'old style" of armored cable, dates back to the very early 20th century...)

Comment: Also don't use receptacles with spring-loaded back stabs. Either make hooks on the ends of the wires or use the receptacles that accept straight ends but hold them with a screw compression clamp.